# One key and multiple value problem in multimap

Tags: c++

I'm working on a problem using map.

I used multi map to have one key with multiple value to solve this problem. However, it does not work. I think the problem is when I insert elements into multimap, but I cannot find anything wrong with that code. 
Here is the instruction: 
You will be given two words and a mapping between characters. Your task is to write a function that will check if the first word can be translated into the second word. You need to use the character mappings to decipher the first word and see if it matches the second. The character mappings can be applied repeatedly to each character.
"works works" is a match, each letter maps to itself

"out the" is a match. First you check o and t. From the given mapping you have o->c, c->t. Then check u and h. From the mapping u->h. Finally check t and e. From the mapping t->e. Since all characters could be resolved, out and the are a match.

"good worm" is not a match. First check g and w, g does not map to w. At the first occurrence of character not mapping, you can conclude it is not a match.
My problem is when t mapped to two words e, f. And my codes does not pass the test of it->of
Thank you

```
int checkmatch(char x, char y, std::multimap<char,char>mapp){
   if (x == y) return 1;
   while (mapp.find(x) != mapp.end()){
      if(mapp.find(x)->second==y)
         return 1;
      else
         x=mapp.find(x)->second;
      }   
      return 0;
}

bool wordsMatch( std::vector<std::pair<char, char>> & mappings, std::string leftWord, std::string rightWord ){
   // Your code goes here
   std::multimap<char,char> mapp;
   std::vector<char>value;
   int n=mappings.size();
   int result=0;
   char p1[leftWord.length()], p2[rightWord.length()];
   for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
      mapp.insert(std::pair<char,char>(mappings[i].first, mappings[i].second));  
   }
   if (leftWord.length() != rightWord.length()){
      return false;}

   for(int i=0; i<leftWord.length();i++){
      p1[i]=leftWord[i];
      p2[i]=rightWord[i];}
   for(int i=0; i<leftWord.length();i++){
      result +=checkmatch(p1[i],p2[i], mapp);  
   }
   if (result == leftWord.length())
      return true;
   else
      return false;

}
```

Comment: What debugger do you have access to? Single step through your code to see where your code deviates from your expected algorithm. It's going to be significantly faster than trying to simulate the code in your head and finding the bug that way. Mechanics have access to diagnostic codes. Carpenters have access to tape measures. Programmers have access to debuggers.

Comment: I'm not able to use clion or dev c++, only thing I could use is an idle called zybook (it works like leecode). 
The problem I think is this line: mapp.insert(std::pair<char,char>(mappings[i].first, mappings[i].second)); }
I'm not sure if it insert multiple value for one key.

Comment: What's the problem with that line? What operating system are you on? Certainly there's a development environment or IDE available to you.

Comment: According to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/insert, your use of `insert` here will still insert the second value of pair if the first value of pair already exists as a key in the `multimap`.

Comment: You could also remove the loop and just do `mapp.insert(mappings.begin(), mappings.end());`

Comment: when it inserted elements to the multimap, I don't think it included the other value of key t
here is the mapping from the instruction
c->t
i->r
k->p
o->c
r->o
t->e
t->f
u->h
w->p
So, when I called function checkMatch with (t,f, multimap), the pair t,f is not in multimap.
I used Windows, and dev C++

Comment: Not super familiar with dev C++. I feel like Visual Studio Community Edition 2019 might be better (that's what I use on my home PC), which comes with a built in debug environment (no idea what it does behind the scenes, I just press a button and it debugs magically). Of course, you probably don't have time to learn a new IDE, I understand.

Comment: My professor use an idle on website, and it works like leetcode, all we have to do is just code the function. He takes care the input.

Comment: To find all values that match a key in a multimap, use `equal_range`. `find` will only find one of the values (and it's not guaranteed to be the same one every time either). https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/equal_range

Comment: Although equal_range will only tell you what characters can be _directly_ mapped to from a given character. If _none_ of those match, you'll still need to check the second hops, and third, and etc...

Comment: Although you might already be populating the multimap with all possible characters given a starting character, in which case carry on. Otherwise search for "how to find if a path exists between nodes in a directed graph".

Comment: OMGGGGG! Thank you sir, I used equal_range and changed the code. It worked. I passed the last unit test. I appreciated a lottt. Thank youuuu

Comment: Whenever you use a standard library container, look at the documentation on cppreference. I usually do a google search like "std::vector cppreference" to get to the page (replace vector with container of your choice). There you can see all of the public interface for that container and save yourself lots of time.